# Increment value in vector of pairs

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, constants

I am trying to iterate over a vector of pair and i need to increment one of the elements in the pair by doing this :

```
for (std::vector<std::pair<Process *, int> >::const_iterator it = process.begin();   it != process.end(); it++) {
        if (queue.size() == 0)
          break;                                                                                                                                                                                 
        while (queue.size() > 0 && it->second < threadsPerProcess * 2) {
          it->first->send(queue.front());
          queue.pop_front();
          ++it->second; // value i am trying to increment
        }
 }
```

could someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
for (std::vector<std::pair<Process *, int> >::const_iterator it = process.begin();   it != process.end(); it++) {
```

to this:

```
for (std::vector<std::pair<Process *, int> >::iterator it = process.begin();   it != process.end(); it++) {
```

so that you actually modify the elements you are iterating over.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `const_iterator`, if you modifying content, use simple `iterator`.